# how to implement custom BinaryIO wrappable in TextIOWrapper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, stream

I have a stream that I can read packets of bytes from. I want to be able to use file operations on that stream like `shutil.copyfileobj` and be able to wrap it around `io.FileIOWrapper`.

I wrote the following code:

```
import io
from typing import BinaryIO, Iterator


def my_read() -> Iterator[bytes]:
    """Read a chunk from my stream"""
    yield b""


def my_close():
    """Close my stream"""
    pass


###############################################################################


def my_read_to_generator() -> Iterator[int]:
    """Wrapper to read one byte at a time. Is it needed?"""
    for b in my_read():
        for c in b:
            yield c


class Stdin(BinaryIO):
    def read(self, size: int = -1) -> bytes:
        a = bytearray()
        for c in my_read_to_generator():
            a.append(c)
            if len(a) == size:
                break
        return bytes(a)

    def close(self):
        my_close()


stream = Stdin()
io.TextIOWrapper(stream)
```

I am using `my_read_to_generator` to accommodate for `read` `size` argument. However, the code works on python3.12, but fails on python3.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/tmp/1.py", line 23, in <module>                                                                                                  
    io.TextIOWrapper(stream)                                                                                                              
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

I am not sure if I should be using BinaryIO or something else.

How should I implement my own binary file io object? Using BinaryIO, IOBase, RawIOBase, BufferedIOBase? typing module or io module? Which functions should I override?

If I inherit from `io.RawIOBase` then it is incompatible with constructor argument of `TextIOWrapper`: `Stdin" is incompatible with "IO[bytes]" (Pyright reportArgumentType)`.

I read https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html but it does not say, *when* to use which class.